# Action of momentum operator on position eigenstate i.e., $\hat{P}|x\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum

I was trying to calculate commutator $\left[\hat{P}, \hat{T}(\vec{dx})\right]$ where $\hat{P}$ is momentum operator and $ \hat{T}(\vec{dx})$ is Translation operator

My approach:
I tried calculating the terms
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{P} \hat{T}(\vec{dx}) |x\rangle \text{ and }  \hat{T}(\vec{dx})\hat{P}|x\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
Now I know that $\hat{T}(\vec{dx})|x\rangle = |x + dx\rangle$ but I dont know how will $\hat{P}$ operate on state $|x\rangle$ or $|x + dx\rangle$

Comment: Maybe expand $|x\rangle $ in the basis of momentum eigenstates. However, I think you should be able to deduce the commutator by referring to the definition of the translation operator in terms of the momentum operator.

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113808/what-is-hatpx-rangle?rq=1), and [further](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511669/eigenvalues-of-the-momentum-operator-in-position-basis?rq=1), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592736/momentum-operator-matrix-elements-in-position-representation?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *know* that $\langle p|x\rangle = e^{-ixp/\hbar}/\sqrt{2\pi/\hbar}$, so
$$
\langle p|\hat T (dx)|x\rangle = \langle p|x+dx\rangle= \frac{e^{-ip(x+dx)/\hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\\ =\langle p|x\rangle e^{-ipdx/\hbar}= \langle p|e^{-i\hat Pdx/\hbar}|x\rangle \\ \leadsto 
\hat T (dx)= e^{-i\hat P dx /\hbar}, ~~\implies~~ [\hat P, \hat T]=0.
$$

Heed the counterintuitive minus sign in the exponent: kets translate oppositely to functions and bras!

---

*Geeky* : If you enjoy integrating delta functions by parts,  you might well consider two handy representations of this unitary operator,
$$
\hat T(a) =\int \!\! dp~|p\rangle e^{-ipa/\hbar}\langle p| = \int \!\! dx~|x\rangle e^{-a \partial_x}\langle x|.
$$